# Changing the functionality of many ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax

Suppose, you're working on a project that does a lot of `jQuery.ajax` requests. Now you want to display a kind of `"loading..."` message while a request is running.

How could you do that? You can't change all the `$.ajax` calls (e.g. there are too many or it's important to have consistent behavior)

Need some guidance on this... Thanks...

Comment: sorry not sure how to start on this....

Comment: Did you try googling? Then you did try something. And: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated?cb=1 Wait, the homework tag disappeared!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this page: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

You will see `.ajaxStart()`. Check that page and I'm sure you will figure it out. Since your profile says: 'very keen in learning new things', I'm not going to give it all :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check this: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/

In that page, you'll see:

For show a loading message whenever an Ajax request starts (and none is already active).

```
$("#loading").ajaxStart(function(){
   $(this).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listening all ajax events like this :

```
$("#loading").bind("ajaxSend", function() {
    $(this).show();
}).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

more info in this page : http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events